# How to create a virtual SQL Server table from a csv file

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple use cases whereby I need to effectively create a virtual sql server table from a csv source and I need to do it preferably using pure sql on the fly- ie not using a procedure. To provide some context, I need to wire up this code in a third party reporting engine; which is talking to sql server in addition to other multiple data sources such as oracle etc.

This can be done in POSTGRE using a simple function split_part because that function includes the ability to search the csv concate string for the position of the field delimiter; example ',' comma separator. Unfortunately, sql server has a similar function STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator ) but notice it does NOT have the position aspect SPLIT_PART(string, delimiter, position) offered in POSTGre.

Example source csv:
Row 1 a,b,c,d
Row 2 e,f,g,h
etc

Output - using POSTGre db but require same for sql server

```
select split_part(p.Lines, ',',1) As Col1,
split_part(p.Lines, ',',2) As Col2,
split_part(p.Lines, ',',3) As Col3,
split_part(p.Lines, ',',4) As Col4
from ( select unnest(string_to_array(:csvdata, chr(10))) as Lines)p
```

Any solution?

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` *still* does not have an ordinal position column, no; it's been heavily requested since it was added but Microsoft appear to have made no attempt to add it. You'll need to use a splitter that does offer such a column, such as by using a JSON splitter, a CLR function, or a tally splitter (such as `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`).

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? (SELECT @@VERSION;)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4517790) - 15.0.2070.41 (X64)   Oct 28 2019 19:56:59   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allows to query *.csv file as a virtual DB table on a file system.

Here is a minimal reproducible example.

**SQL**

```
SELECT *
FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\Temp\Quark.csv'
   , FORMATFILE = 'e:\Temp\Quark.xml'  
   , ERRORFILE = 'e:\Temp\Quark.err'
   , FIRSTROW = 2 -- real data starts on the 2nd row
   , MAXERRORS = 100
   ) AS tbl;
```

**Quark.csv**

```
"ID"|"Name"|"Color"|"LogDate"|"Unknown"
41|Orange|Orange|2018-09-09 16:41:02.000|
42|Cherry, Banana|Red,Yellow||
43|Apple|Yellow|2017-09-09 16:41:02.000|
```

**Quark.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <RECORD>
      <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='|' MAX_LENGTH="70"/>
      <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='|' MAX_LENGTH="70" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='|' MAX_LENGTH="70" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='|' MAX_LENGTH="70" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\r\n' MAX_LENGTH="70" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
   </RECORD>
   <ROW>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="ID" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Name" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Color" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="LogDate" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Unknown" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
   </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------------+------------+-------------------------+---------+
| ID |      Name      |   Color    |         LogDate         | Unknown |
+----+----------------+------------+-------------------------+---------+
| 41 | Orange         | Orange     | 2018-09-09 16:41:02.000 | NULL    |
| 42 | Cherry, Banana | Red,Yellow | NULL                    | NULL    |
| 43 | Apple          | Yellow     | 2017-09-09 16:41:02.000 | NULL    |
+----+----------------+------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Hi but as I said, due to my constraint's of using a third party reporting tool it has to be done on the fly via sql server sql.....

Comment: @ScottAli, the suggested solution is pure T-SQL, one single statement, on the fly.

Comment: thanks but not what I meant by "on the fly" as I already know about this method but it requires that you first create the source csv or xml file; which opens up other issues in of itself.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken - split_part parses a delimited string into component elements and returns the desired element from that string.

To accomplish this in SQL Server - we can use charindex and substring, or you can use a combination of splitting the string to a table, and rolling the values back up in a GROUP BY.

Here is a function that can be used to return up to 12 elements from a delimited string:

```
  ALTER Function [dbo].[fnSplitString_12Columns] (
        @pString varchar(8000)
      , @pDelimiter char(1)
        )
Returns Table
   With schemabinding
     As
 Return 

 Select InputString = @pString
      , p01_pos = p01.pos
      , p02_pos = p02.pos
      , p03_pos = p03.pos
      , p04_pos = p04.pos
      , p05_pos = p05.pos
      , p06_pos = p06.pos
      , p07_pos = p07.pos
      , p08_pos = p08.pos
      , p09_pos = p09.pos
      , p10_pos = p10.pos
      , p11_pos = p11.pos
      , p12_pos = p12.pos
      , col_01 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, 1, p01.pos - 2))
      , col_02 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, p01.pos, p02.pos - p01.pos - 1))
      , col_03 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, p02.pos, p03.pos - p02.pos - 1))
      , col_04 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, p03.pos, p04.pos - p03.pos - 1))
      , col_05 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, p04.pos, p05.pos - p04.pos - 1))
      , col_06 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, p05.pos, p06.pos - p05.pos - 1))
      , col_07 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, p06.pos, p07.pos - p06.pos - 1))
      , col_08 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, p07.pos, p08.pos - p07.pos - 1))
      , col_09 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, p08.pos, p09.pos - p08.pos - 1))
      , col_10 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, p09.pos, p10.pos - p09.pos - 1))
      , col_11 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, p10.pos, p11.pos - p10.pos - 1))
      , col_12 = ltrim(substring(v.inputString, p11.pos, p12.pos - p11.pos - 1))
   From (Values (concat(@pString, replicate(@pDelimiter, 12))))                 As v(inputString)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, 1) + 1))           As p01(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, p01.pos) + 1))     As p02(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, p02.pos) + 1))     As p03(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, p03.pos) + 1))     As p04(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, p04.pos) + 1))     As p05(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, p05.pos) + 1))     As p06(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, p06.pos) + 1))     As p07(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, p07.pos) + 1))     As p08(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, p08.pos) + 1))     As p09(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, p09.pos) + 1))     As p10(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, p10.pos) + 1))     As p11(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(@pDelimiter, v.inputString, p11.pos) + 1))     As p12(pos);
```

The function also returns the starting position in the string for each element.  If you use the function to return only the first 4 elements - the rest of the code will be factored out of the final query.

If you have more than 12 columns you can extend to as many as needed.  Performance may be affected by the size of the string (8000 vs MAX) and how many elements are parsed - but the only way to be sure will be to test different methods to see which performs best for your data.